# How to open http.server at the same IP address every time in python

Tags: python, httpserver

What happen to me is that when I open the python server using the command↓

```
python -m http.server
```

It does open the server at some IP address but when I change to different WIFI connection then my server IP address also gets changed.

So is there any way so that when I open the server then every time it opens at the same IP address. Or is there any module to do that.

Comment: If your machine no longer has some IP address assigned, other machines no longer can reach it at that address. Doesn't matter what you do in your Python code. On the same machine, you can connect to: http://localhost:8000/ - otherwise you need some kind of DNS or proxy service with static IP.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do with this HTTP server later on in your code, but in general you might want to consider using the `http` module (and thus its `server` sub module) from within your Python code, instead of creating it directly via command line as in your example above.

As mentioned in the [official `http` module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#module-http.server), one can instance such an HTTP server like this:

```py
def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    server_address = ('', 8000)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

As you can see in the example above, you can also set the IP address your server should listen to (via the `server_address` variable).

Comment: Using `http` module from code won't help there. `http.server` listens on all interfaces by default.

Comment: @PiotrPraszmo Yes, by default. But you can specify the interface/address you want it to listen on, if you want. So I still don't see why this answer has been downvoted.

Comment: By default all local addresses are being listened on. The way you are describing can only reduce that number.

Comment: @PiotrPraszmo Well, ok I can see your point now.

Comment: @codebyAbhishekBharti Please consider accepting this answer if it solved your problem :)